# How to parse xml file in vim?

Tags: android, vim

I am currently working on an android project. And now i wish to complete a job: Parsing a xml file called `AndroidManifest.xml` and get some attribute from it. And set to some values in vim.

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.base.module.callhistory"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <application android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
          android:icon="@drawable/call_history">
        <activity android:name="HistoryMainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="HistoryListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="DetailListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I want to parse `package="com.base.module.callhistory"` and `HistoryListActivity` in `<activity android:name="HistoryMainActivity"`. Then i can use this two value to compose a command to launch my app automatically. I just set these values by hand. But i think if vim can parse this file and set these values automatically, it's must very cool.

Answer (score 1):

Consider xmlstarlet, xmllint --xpath

Otherwise, you can use perl or python to achieve your goal *if* you have it compiled in (usually packaged versions do)

Regardless of that, you might still use nomarl search (`/`) patterns with <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to replace the tag contents

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement as you, and I just wrote a custom python script for this task.